# IIS ASP.NET .aspx page 400 error - No trace and all handlers in place

Tags: asp.net, iis, handler, windows-server-2012-r2

I am re-platforming an ASP.Net site onto Server 2012R2 using .NetFramework 2 and WOW64.  I have had everything running just fine until something changed during the licensing of a 3rd party component-which failed to complete

I was serving .aspx pages without an issue.

I have the same code running on another installation.

No matter what I try I cant get past the 400 error.

I have tried everything I can find to restore the IIS - reinstalling .NetFramework 3.5 and all the required components through ServerManager incl IIS, all of the tools. I have tried running the DISM clean up tools and even gave the "aspnet_regiis -i -enable" a try.

I have tried to get a page trace running but that is not producing any output.
I have turned custom errors off and enabled trace for the site
I have checked the IIS logs and get nothing useful - just the 400 error.
I have checked the HTTP.logs and get nothing
I have checked file permissions
I have checked the worker processes and application pools
I have checked the GAC to ensure that the assemblies are loaded and valid
There is nothing useful in the event logs

Failed Request logging shows the request being picked up by the handler but then failing.

I have a single page test site and I am able to serve HTML and .ASP pages but not .ASPX

I've checked the handlers are in place - but they dont seem to be handling the .aspx pages - if I remove the handler from the site I get a different error - so it looks like the right handler is getting hit.  It looks to me like a dependancy for the handler is missing - but everything looks ok.

I'm at a loss to what to try next - other than starting the project from scratch :(

Any thoughts would be appreciated

Comment: Can you post the log contents of the failed request trace? also this is a very generic error, you can try to debug the cause using IIS Debug Diagnostics Tool, this tool will generate detail log file, which will help you to identify the problem.

Comment: can you build + ruin on your dev computer? Is this a asp.net web site, or a asp.net web site application?